# Does encrypting Time Machine erase the recovery partition?

Tags: time-machine, encryption, recovery-hd

I have prepared my external hard drive to be used for Time Machine backup by erasing and creating a new working recovery partition on it. I am ready to start the first backup, which I want to be encrypted. The message says this will erase the disk. Does this include erasing my recovery partition?  If so, how can I both encrypt my backup drive and retain it as a recovery disk?

Comment: is it a hidden partition?

Comment: Yes. standard invisible partition.

Comment: That should be enough for TM not to see it :)

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help. I went ahead yesterday, it took all night and a good part of today. But it seems to be working normally now. All partitions still there.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked as planed :)

Answer (score 2):

If you make your Recovery partition as Hidden partition, then the Time Machine wont touch it since it does not see it as available disk space.